# I installed Vaadin eclipse plugin but I can't see it in the new menu nor in preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I installed the Vaadin plugin from the eclipse market place, and then I restarted my eclipse, I was surprised that nothing came up on the File->New wizard dialog: 
[image]

I check in the installed plugins, and I can clearly see that the vaadin plug-in is installed: 
[image]

Any idea what am I missing?

I'm using eclipse neon on Windows 7 machine.

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
```

Comment: I didn't use the marketplace, but the `Help -> Install new software` menu and providing the `http://vaadin.com/eclipse` URL for Eclipse 3.5 on their [page](https://vaadin.com/eclipse). The versions installed seem to be exactly what you have so I'm unsure if it's relevant, but I can see all the options in the wizard, so you might as well try this method and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue using Eclipse Oxygen. After trying various things, I decided to try installing the plugin on an older version of Eclipse. Installing on Eclipse Neon worked, using the `Help -> Install new software` path, as outlined in the previous answer by Morfic.